# How to integrate a function based view into a class based view in Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-views

In my site I have 2 sections for users. The user posts page and the profile page. The profile page has all their info on it, so username, description, first/last name, etc. And the user posts page has all their posts on it. However, I want to integrate them together somehow.

Here is some of the code.

Here is the view for the User Posts

```py
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'mainapp/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User,username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-published_date')
```

As you can see, I am returning the specific users posts.

And now here is my profile view

```py
def view_profile(request,pk=None):
        if pk:
            user_profile = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            user_profile = request.user
        context = {'user':user_profile}
        return render(request,'mainapp/profile.html',context)
```

It returns all the user's info.

Here is the HTML code for both the profile and user posts page

```html
{% block content %}


<div class="profile-page-container">

    <div class="profile-page-info">
<div class="profile-page-banner">
    <div class="profile-page-banner-background">
        <!-- <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/30/01/05/milky-way-2695569_960_720.jpg" alt="{{ user }}'s Background Image" > -->
    </div>
    <div class="profile-page-banner-text">
<h2 title="{{ user }}" id="username-profile-page">{{ user|safe|linebreaksbr|truncatechars_html:25 }} {% if user.userprofileinfo.verified %} <span class="image-profile-verified"><img draggable="false" title="Verified User" class="verifed" src="{% static 'images\verified.png' %}" alt="verified" width="25" height="25" srcset=""></span> {% endif %}</h2>

<p>{{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }}</p><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="profile-page-user-desc-box">
<p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.description }}</p>
<a href="{{ user.userprofileinfo.website }}"><p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.website }}</p></a>
<p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.joined_date |date:"F d Y" }}</p>
</div>
<br>
{% if user.userprofileinfo.image %}
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.userprofileinfo.image.url }}" alt="{{ user }}'s Profile Picture'">
{% endif %}
</div>
<div class="user-post-user-profile-page">
    <h1 title="{{ user }}">Posts</h1>

{% for post in posts %}
<div class="content">
<div class="post">
        <h1 class='posttitle'>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <img class="user-image" src="{{ post.author.userprofileinfo.image.url }}" alt="pfp" width="20%" height="20%">
                {% if post.published_date %}
                    <!-- <div class="postdate">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i> &nbsp; <p>Posted {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>   -->
                    <div class="posted-by">
                        <p>Posted by <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong>  {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="pub-post" href="{% url 'mainapp:post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
                {% endif %}

              <p class='postcontent' >{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the user_posts page

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="sidebar">
        <p class="active" href="#">{{ view.kwargs.username }}</p>
        <button class="commentbtn"><a class="aclass" href="#">Connect with {{ view.kwargs.username }}</a></button>
        <p>{{ user.userprofileinfo.email }}</p>
        <p>Lorem</p>
      </div>


{% for post in posts %}
<div class="content">
<div class="post">
        <h1 class='posttitle'>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <img class="user-image" src="{{ post.author.userprofileinfo.image.url }}" alt="pfp" width="20%" height="20%">
                {% if post.published_date %}
                    <!-- <div class="postdate">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i> &nbsp; <p>Posted {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>   -->
                    <div class="posted-by">
                        <p>Posted by <strong>{{ post.author }}</strong>  {{ post.published_date|timesince }} ago</p>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                    <a class="pub-post" href="{% url 'mainapp:post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
                {% endif %}

              <p class='postcontent' >{{ post.text|safe|linebreaksbr }}</p>
                  </div>
                  </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have tried to merge the FBV into the CBV by cutting it and pasting it below the get_queryset method So like this

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    #... code here
def view_profile(request,pk=None):
    #... code here
```

However this did not work. I am just curious as to how I can integrate both together so I can have the best of both worlds in one place

EDIT: Here are the models

```py
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',
                                           processors=[ResizeToFill(150, 150)],
                                           default='default.jpg',
                                           format='JPEG',
                                           options={'quality': 60})
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,default=timezone.now)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and now the post

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField()
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,null=True,blank=True,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',blank=True,null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files',blank=True,null=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True,auto_now_add=True)
    comments_disabled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    NSFW = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    spoiler = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want 1 profile view that also has a list of posts by the user?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Can you add your `models`, as i'm assuming you have a foreignkey relationship with from user to posts.

Comment: I added the post and userprofileinfo models at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also in continuation to Ian answer, if you have a direct relationship between models then you can simply get the posts for the particular user like this:

```
def view_profile(request,pk=None):
        if pk:
            user_profile = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
            user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(user__id=pk)   #<---add these
        else:
            user_profile = request.user
            user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(user__id = request.user.id)   #<---add these
        context = {
                   'user':user_profile,
                   'user_posts':user_posts
                  }
        return render(request,'mainapp/profile.html',context)
```

Comment: @jeremy_lord Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple class based view for getting a user:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'mainapp/profile.html'
    context_object_name = 'user'
```

Relationships (foreign keys) can be followed backwards. Every foreign key has a reverse relationship defined (unless you set `reverse_name` to `+`...) it will usually be named `<modelname>_set` on the model referenced by the foreign key

For example, the following two lines are equivalent

```
Post.objects.filter(author=user)
user.post_set.all()
```

This can be used in your profile template

```
{% for post in user.post_set.all %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```